# How to understand "in line" and "in groups"? Are they adverbials of means or adverbials of place?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> (1) When he got to the bus stop, there were already many people there. They
>   were ***standing in line.***
>
> (2) The students sat ***in groups***.

Are they adverbials of means or adverbials of place? Can you describe the scenes for me?

Comment: An adverbial of place will need a noun (place or location) after the preposition. For example, *in the room* (*the room* is where someone or something is *in*), *on the table* (*the table* is where someone or something is *on*).

Answer (score 3):

An adverbial phrase of place will need a noun (place or location) after the preposition.

For example,
***in*** the room (*the room* is where someone or something is *in*),
***on*** the table (*the table* is where someone or something is *on*).

Your case of ***in groups*** is quite clear, *groups* is not a place. (You can't *walk to groups*. If it's a place, you usually can walk there.) *In groups* here is an adverbial phrase of manner.

The case of ***in line*** is a little tricky, but try not to be confused. The phrase *in line* is idiomatic, meaning *one behind another in a line or queue*. So again, it's an adverbial phrase of manner. Saying ***"They were standing in line,"*** is quite different from ***"They were standing in the line."*** (Only the latter--*in the line*--is an adverbial phrase of place.)

Comment: If "in line" is an adverbial clause of manner, so  it means "They were standing by forming a line". What about is an adverbial clause of result ? That means "They were standing and they are forming a line."

Comment: Here is one way put it as an adverbial clause of result, *"They were standing such that a line was formed"*. Typical result clauses have either *so ... that*, *such ... that*, or sometimes just *that*.

Answer (score 3):

As for describing the scenes, *sitting in groups* means that groups of students were sitting together. Perhaps there are multiple tables in the classroom, and the students are grouped around the table, Or maybe the students are in a gymnasium, and they are sitting in small groups, dispersed around the gym floor. In the images below, the classrooms are empty now, but students in the top classroom sit in *rows*, while students in the bottom classroom sit in *groups*.

[image: rows vs groups]

*Standing in line* simply means there was a line (or queue) of people at the bus stop, presumably waiting to board the bus.

[image]

Comment: You used all my bandwidth:)

Comment: @Noah The pictures are worth it! I love'em! :)

Comment: @Noah - Actually, the original images are [much bigger](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-bkxVLX8N7cU/TzQIauGIlxI/AAAAAAAAEJc/2CJE8Qelbgw/s1600/Andrew_Classroom_De_La_Salle_University.jpeg). I took the time to crop them to save bandwidth.